# Parameterized queries on iteration

Tags: c#, t-sql, parameterized

I am inserting a web form into the database and so using parameterized queries. I have a CheckBoxList. How can I iterate over CheckBoxList, create an insert statement for every checked thing (many-to-many), and keep this parameterized and executed in one swoop?

I have this right now:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO resources (url, submitted_by, author_name) VALUES (@url, @submitted_by, @author_name);";
foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected = true)
        {
            query += "; INSERT INTO ";
        }
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submitted_by", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author_name", TextBox3.Text);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "Added to database.";
    }
```

As you can see it's unfinished. Any suggestions?

Comment: Each checked item needs to generate an insert for one set of `url, submitted, author`?

Comment: @tzaman: No, each checked item would need to create an INSERT statement like this: `INSERT INTO phones_resources (phone_id, resource_id) VALUES (@phone_id, @resource_id);`.

Comment: Ok. So, given a `ListItem` where do you get the associated `phone_id, resource_id`?

Comment: Ah, actually I hadn't realized that resource_id would be the result of the first insert, so I'd have to execute that one first anyway. I guess I will just have to create a unique SQLCommand for these. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can still do all the ListItems in one go, I'll write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to generate unique named parameters for each item in your collection, then add the associated values in later:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var listParams = CheckBoxList1.Items
                     .Where(li => li.Selected)
                     .Select(li, idx => new 
                     {
                         PhoneString = String.Format("@phone_id{0}", idx),
                         PhoneValue = GetPhoneId(li),
                         ResourceString = String.Format("@resource_id{0}", idx),
                         ResourceValue = GetResourceId(li)
                     };
foreach (var param in listParams)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO phones_resources (phone_id, resource_id) 
                          VALUES ({0}, {1});", 
                          param.PhoneString, param.ResourceString);
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(builder.ToString(), conn);
foreach (var param in listParams)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.PhoneString, param.PhoneValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.ResourceString, param.ResourceValue);
}
```

I'm assuming you have some way of getting associated `phone_id, resource_id` from any given `ListItem` - you can just plug that in where I've put the placeholder `Get___` functions.

Note: Switched to a `StringBuilder` - it's much better than building up a string with repeated `+=`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using .NET 2.0 but I've adapted this to fit. I'd hoped that I wouldn't have had to do things in this way, but it works out fine and wasn't so bad after your encouragement.

The LINQ statement is a nice reference and I'll try to remember to check it out when I get a chance to mess with newer .NET frameworks (probably Mono actually).

Comment: @cookiecaper - you're welcome! I was facing a similar situation recently myself; I ended up generalizing this approach by adding an extension method on `SqlParameterCollection` called `AddFromDict` which took a `Dictionary<string, object>` of parameter name/values and added them all. So now I just populate a `parameters` dict and then call `cmd.Parameters.AddFromDict(parameters);` :)